# Avoid redirect page in c# masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to Avoid redirect content page on query string in c# masterpage.

my all pages are redirecting in query string for example default.aspx?productId=1001

I used global file to redirect

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string productId= string.Empty;
       Regex regexstore = new Regex(@"store/(.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        MatchCollection matchesstore = regexstore.Matches(oldpath);
        if (matchesstore.Count > 0)
        {
            categoryId = matchesstore[0].Groups[1].ToString();
            incoming.RewritePath(String.Concat("../product.aspx?productId=", productId).ToLower(), false);    
        }
    }
```

my page source code is showing action like this

```
<form method="post" action="store/product/1001?productId=1001" >
```

while ushing AjaxToolTit Popup Control the page url is also showing store/product/1001?productId=1001

Comment: Can you show how oldPath is defined?

Comment: Doesn't look as though you've included the complete code

Comment: @timothyclifford Simply man I can't include the all code my problem is just the page is getting redirect on query string on modal pop click